# Open a remote file with vim. Email-like username

Tags: email, authentication, vim, ftp

I have a problem authenticating to my ftp with vim.
That because my username is an email address like this

424242@myhostingsite.com

So I should write

```
Nread fpt//424242@myhostingsite.com@myftpsite.com/
```

But I receive a warning and (obviously) It doesn't work. 
Is there a way to escape the first @ char?

Comment: Does the following help: http://www.aota.net/forums/showthread.php?t=16139

Comment: @Dominik: I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`Nread ftp://"424242@myhostingsite.com"@myftpsite.com/`

Comment: Then try either of: `Nread ftp://424242\@myhostingsite.com@myftpsite.com/` or `Nread ftp://424242~@myhostingsite.com@myftpsite.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Nread ftp://424242+myhostingsite.com@myftpsite.com/
```

Comment: No... still no luck. I'm starting to think that there is no way to escape the char

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I've got exactly the same problem. It seems that there is one solution but not as comfortable. You can omit the user name and type it when vim ask for it.

If I find other solution i will post it here.